# How do I swap one div with another on a certain time

Tags: javascript, datetime, html, if-statement, show-hide

I have 2 divs (#divA & #divB). I want one to display #divA, then on a certain date hide divA, and show #divB.

DivA would represent 'Coming soon' and DivB would represent 'Now Here!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
if (new Date() < new Date(2013,1,1)) {
   document.getElementById("diva").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("divb").style.display = "none";
} else {
   document.getElementById("diva").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("divb").style.display = "block";
}
```

This checks if todays date (`new Date()`) is before a selected date (`new Date(2013,1,1)`) if it is then it shows `diva` and hides (`display = "none"`) `divb` - else the reverse

Comment: WOW! You're AWeSome!!! That was so Fast, ok!
Let me check if this works and I'll be back!!

Thank you so much for your Time!
i'll be right back!

Comment: Again Thanks for the help, How would I get in contact with you if I need more help... We could work out some sort of arrangement, if that's something your open to.

Thanks Again,
Steve

Comment: @Steve Just post your questions on here and someone will be able to help you ....

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display:none` to hide the Div and `display:block` to show it

```
<div id="divA" style="display:none;">Coming Soon </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use setInterval() to achieve that, e.g,

assuming you are using jQuery and the page should look like:

```
<div id="A"> comming soon</div>
<div id="B" style="display:none"> Now here! </div>

<script>
function check_if_some_content_is_loaded(){
  //your implementation code here...
  is_loaded = ....

  if(is_loaded){
    $("#A").toggle(); 
    $("#B").toggle();
  }
}

$(function(){
  // call the "check ..." function every 10 seconds.
  setInterval("check_if_some_content_is_loaded()", 10000);   
})

</script>
```

Comment: Hi there! What do you mean use the setinterval to do that?

Comment: Where do I add this Line of Code?

Comment: This is what I have for the code and it works perfectly, I was just wondering where exactly do add the code on here.... this is my working script I just dont know how to add the interval check to it...

Comment: WHERE DO I ADD THE INTERVAL CHECK? - - -<!--DIV SWAP CODE-->
<script type="text/javascript">if (new Date() < new Date(2012,3,25)) {
   document.getElementById("huPriceA").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("huPriceB").style.display = "none";
} else {
   document.getElementById("huPriceA").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("huPriceB").style.display = "block";
} 
// call the "check ..." function every 10 seconds.
//setInterval("check_if_it_is_some_date_today()", 10000); 
</script>
<!--DIV SWAP CODE-->

Answer (score -2):

You have to use a server site technology like php, i think. No use of loading all the stuff to client side. Your web page will be slow. Just see if possible to use php.

Comment: If your web page gets noticeably slower from a div and a couple of lines of JavaScript, it's time to find a new web host.